Do we get different canonical forms of a PDE when we interchange the rules of transformation among the new variables?
Find the canonical form of the PDE $y^2u_{xx} + 2xy u_{xy} + 2x^2u_{yy} + xu_x = 0.$
Firstly, I tried to find the characteristic equation of the given PDE. This will be precisely,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy\pm\sqrt{4x^2y^2-8x^2y^2}}{2y^2}=\frac{xy\pm ixy}{y^2}=\frac{x}{y}(1\pm i).$$
Solving the ODEs we have, $$ydy=(1\pm i)xdx\implies \frac{y^2}{2}=(1\pm i)\frac{x^2}{2}+c_{1,2}.$$
We have,  $\frac{y^2-x^2}{2}-i\frac{x^2}{2}=c_1=f_1(x,y)$ qnd $$\frac{y^2-x^2}{2}+i\frac{x^2}{2}=c_2=f_2(x,y)$$ where, $c_1$ md $c_2$ are arbitrary constants.
We fix, $\xi=f_1,\eta=f_2$
Assuming $\alpha=\text{Re}(\xi)=\frac{y^2-x^2}{2},$ $\beta=\text{Im}(\xi)=-\frac{x^2}{2}.$
Next, I tried changing the variables in the PDE to $\alpha,\beta.$
We note that,

$u_x=-x(u_{\alpha}+u_{\beta}),$

$u_{xx}=-(u_{\alpha}+u_{\beta})+x^2(u_{\alpha\alpha}+2u_{\alpha\beta}+u_{\beta\beta}),$

$u_y=yu_{\alpha},$

$u_{yy}=u_{\alpha}+y^2u_{\alpha\alpha},$

$u_{xy}=-xy(u_{\alpha\alpha}+u_{\alpha\beta})$


Substituting these in the given PDE and applying the transformations, $\alpha=\frac{y^2-x^2}{2}$ and $\beta=-\frac{x^2}{2},$ we have,
$u_{\alpha\alpha}+u_{\beta\beta}=\frac{\alpha u_{\alpha}+(\alpha-2\beta)u_{\beta}}{2\beta (\beta -\alpha)}$
So, the canonical form we get is,
$$u_{\alpha\alpha}+u_{\beta\beta}=\frac{\alpha u_{\alpha}+(\alpha-2\beta)u_{\beta}}{2\beta (\beta -\alpha)}$$
However, $$u_{\alpha\alpha} + u_{\beta\beta} = \frac{1}{2\beta(\alpha + \beta)} [\alpha u_{\alpha} - (\alpha + 2\beta) u_{\beta}]$$ is given as the canonical form in the book. I saw that they assumed  $\xi=f_2,\eta=f_1.$
But I don't think that I made any mistake. So, my question is, just as it seems in this case,
Do we get different canonical forms of a PDE when we interchange the rules of transformations among the new variables ?
Any help regarding this issue will be highly appreciated.

FYI, the [canonical-transformation] tag is specific to canonical transformations in classical Hamiltonian mechanics. It doesn't have anything to do with canonical forms in PDE.

@Semiclassical Thank you for that information and for editing the post. But what do you think about the original question?
